# What version of SQL Server do I need to move database to production server?

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have just finished developing an ASP.NET on my local Windows XP machine. I used Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server express to develop the site.

My problem is that now I would like to move the SQL Server database from my XP machine to my production server.

I have been reading that SQL Server express cannot export my database. Is this correct?
What would be the best way to export my SQL Server Express database so that I can deploy it on my production server.

IE Do I need to download and install the full blown version of SQL Server? If so what version would be best.

This is very frustating as I have added informaton already to the database and I do no twant to loose all this information if possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server Express will be just fine for this- it uses the same native file format as the more-expensive editions.  All you need to do is detach the db file, copy it to production, attach the production server to the copied file, and you're good... well, mostly good. This won't cover certain things, like logins or maintenance jobs, but all the data, stored procedures, and indexes will be there.

What SQL Server Express will *not* do is export your database into a format like csv.  And even that's not entirely true.  It's just the express management studio that lacks the capability: IIRC if you connect the full edition of the sql server management studio to an express server db you can use the Export features.

Going a step further, if you *really* need to export data from management studio express you can still just set the query window to save query results to file and write a set of export queries.

Comment: Thanks a million Joel for your answer. I know understand it a lot clearer. It is hard being self taught because you do not know if you are doing the right thing or not.